# How do you remove a symbolic link to my own folder?

Tags: unix, symlink

I feel silly enough, and embarrassed by my lack of Unix knowledge...

In the experimental kernel...

```
[root@gala Project2]# ll
...
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 jt jt        17 Nov  5 23:36 Project2 -> /usr/src/Project2
...
```

A `rm -r` gives me this..

```
rm: cannot remove `Project2': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

It is a total knucklehead move/question I know, but I can't find an answer anywhere...

Comment: What about simply `rm Project2`?

Comment: `Cannot rm Project2/, is a directory` :(

Comment: `rm Project2`. No /, no nothing.

Comment: No, Project2 is a link to a directory.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to remove the actual directory.

```
rm -r /usr/src/Project2
```